# Access multidimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
 (   
  [meta_data] => Array
    (
     [5] => Array
       (
         [id] => 33286
         [key] => course_id
         [value] => FF2342
       )
    )
 )
```

To access the desired data I can't use the index (because the order and the indexes somehow are different sometimes).

Is there any way to grab the [value] by [key] —> I mean if the [key] is 'course_id' get [value].

Thanks for your hint!

Comment: Start with a foreach loop!

Comment: If you can't access with `index`, then you should have to use a `foreach`. Loop through the array, check the `key == course_id`, then read value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` on `meta_data` like:

```
$a = [
    
'meta_data' => 
[ 
    '5' => ['id'=> 33286, 'key' => 'course_id', 'value'=> 'FF2342'  ],
    '6' => ['id'=> 1111, 'key' => 'no_course_id', 'value'=> '11111' ],
    '7' => ['id'=> 1111, 'key' => 'course_id', 'value'=> '11111'    ]
    
]   

];

$filterMetaData = array_filter($a['meta_data'], function($subArray){
    if($subArray['key'] === 'course_id')
        return $subArray['value'];
});
print_r($filterMetaData);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 33286
            [key] => course_id
            [value] => FF2342
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1111
            [key] => course_id
            [value] => 11111
        )

)
```

Reference:

- [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: This looks very good. I'll try …GRAZIE MILLE!

Comment: And how would the solution be to just get the [value] only? It's always just one 'course_id', but the order of the index not always the same…

Comment: You can use `array_filter` with [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). if `$filterMetaData`  length > 0 use array map else no 'course_id' find

Comment: @herrseiler Please learn the language basics!!!

Comment: Come on @nice_dev we've all been there, but surely herrseiler you need to inquire a lot and use the documentation is the basis.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini True but we wouldn't apply or jobs(nor magically pass the interviews) or take on any freelancing projects without learning the basics first.